# Python coding for ODE System

Tags: python, math, ode, differential-equations

I have a system of equations described by a function in which.

1. products are constructed from reactants
2. some products break down
3. some percentage of the broken down products are recycled back into initial reactants
4. the system continues to cycle with more products being made until all of the limiting reactant is within the non-cycling product or unusable "lost products"

Given the products do not change in composition. I need the amount of reactant 1 going into the system being directly proportional to the amount of reactant 2 going into the system. Thus, when all of reactant 1 is consumed, no more of reactant 2 is consumed.

Currently the ratio of reactant consumption is constant when there is no recycling of reactants, however, when reactants are cycled in the lines `react1=-R1 - R5` and  `react2=-R2 - R6` the Ratio of reactants used is altered.

The second issue is that during cycling product 2 and the lost products are not continually increasing. Instead they seem to be maintaining a fixed ratio with product 1 and the recycled products respectively.

I assume both issues are caused by how i have attempted to recycle the reactants within the system. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pylab as p

def sample_func (y,t):


    k1 = 10**-4
    k2 = k1/4
    k3 = 0.1
    Recycle0=0.8
    Recycle2=0.7


    R1= -k1*y[0]*y[2]  # Rate of substance 1 consumption
    R2= -k2*y[0]*y[2]  # Rate of substance 2 consumption 
    #These must be constantly proportional to one another 

    R3= 0.2*R1+0.7*R2    #Product 1
    R4= 0.8*R1+0.3*R2    #Product 2 

    R5=R3*Recycle0      #Recycled substance 1 of product 1  
    R6=R3*Recycle2      #Recycled substance 2 of product 1

    R7=R3*(1-Recycle0)
    R8=R3*(1-Recycle2)

    used1 =     R1
    react1=     -R1 - R5 
    used2 =     R2
    react2=     -R2 - R6
    prod1=      -R3 
    prod2=      -R4
    recycledr1 =-R5
    recycledr2 =-R6
    lost1      =-R7
    lost2      =-R8

    return [used1, react1, used2,react2,prod1,prod2, recycledr1,recycledr2,lost1,lost2]





y0=(3,11,3,12,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01)
tspan=np.arange(0,15000,1)
Conc= odeint(sample_func,y0,tspan)



react1          = Conc[:,0]
used1           = Conc[:,1] 
react2          = Conc[:,2]
used2           = Conc[:,3]
prod1           = Conc[:,4]
prod2           = Conc[:,5]
recycledr1      = Conc[:,6]
recycledr2      = Conc[:,7]

print("Consumed R1 & R2 RATIOS AT DIFFERENT TIME POINTS")
print((Conc[1:2,1]-Conc[0:1,1])/(Conc[1:2,3]-Conc[0:1,3]), " 1 HOURS")
print((Conc[50:51,1]-Conc[0:1,1])/(Conc[50:51,3]-Conc[0:1,3]), "50 HOURS")
print((Conc[1000:1001,1]-Conc[0:1,1])/(Conc[1000:1001,3]-Conc[0:1,3]), "1000 HOURS")

plt.plot(tspan,react1,label='react1')
plt.plot(tspan,used1,label='used1')
plt.plot(tspan,react2,label='react2')
plt.plot(tspan,used2,label='used2')
plt.plot(tspan,prod1,label='product1')
plt.plot(tspan,prod2,label='product2')
plt.plot(tspan,recycledr1,label='recycled react 1')
plt.plot(tspan,recycledr2,label='recycled react 2')


plt.xlabel("time (hours)")
plt.ylabel("quantity")
plt.title("production v time")
plt.legend()

p.show()
```

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your actual question here?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I want to know why when I'm attempting to recycle the reactants it's affecting the ratio in which they are being utilized.

Comment: Also I would like to know why product 2, Lost 1 and Lost 2  are not accumulating over time. I want the system to run out of a reactant with the entire quantity becoming stuck in those 3 groups.

Comment: You need an ODE for each reactant.   If those are higher than first order you'll need to express those as first order terms and add them to the set of coupled ODEs.  When you have a complete set I'd recommend an integration scheme like Runga-Kutta (e.g. 4th order with error correction).  We aren't in a position to help you with the physics or chemistry of your problem.  This is a programming site.

Answer (score 0):

OP Duffymo offers a sound observation, in my opinion. You should have an individual ODE for each reactant. Having dealt with problems of this nature myself a few times, I also have a few pieces of advice:

-If each ODE from mass action laws is linear (i.e. no concentrations multiplied together) an implicit approach is easily implemented. I'd suggest starting with the "trapezoidal method" and then implementing higher order integration schemes ad nausea.

-If your system is nonlinear this problem is a bit more difficult to solve. If the magnitudes of all of your euqilibrium/rate constants are similar than you can likely use an explicit integration scheme without too much trouble. Explicit RK4 shouldn't be too hard to implement.

-I would suggest verifying whatever system of differential equations you develop against mass action derivations published in the scientific literature, especially if chemical kinetics is not your area of expertise. If this is a commonly investigated chemical system such a derivation should not be too hard to find.

-If your mass action system has been setup correctly and your integration scheme is working properly conservation of mass should be visibly maintained. To verify this, I would select an element of this system that has equal stoichiometric coefficients in all forms (i.e. carbon in CO2 and CO) and verify that it's abundance in the system is constant.

Here is a link that might help you get started setting up your mass action ODEs

[Law of Mass Action](http://www.science.uwaterloo.ca/~cchieh/cact/c123/massacti.html)